# pandas drop rows after value appears

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Position': [1,2,3,4,5,'Title','Name','copy','Thanks'], 'Winner': [0,0,0,0,0,'Johnson',0,0,0]})
```

I want to drop all the rows after and including the row Johnson appears in. This would give me a dataframe looking like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Position': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Winner': [0,0,0,0,0]})
```

I have tried referencing the index that 'Johnson' appears in the slicing the dataframe using the index. But this didn't work for.

thanks

Comment: _I have tried referencing the index that 'Johnson' appears in the slicing the dataframe using the index. But this didn't work for._ Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need boolean index and `cumsum`:

```
df[df.Winner.eq('Johnson').cumsum().lt(1)]
```

Output:

```
  Position Winner
0        1      0
1        2      0
2        3      0
3        4      0
4        5      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[~df['Winner'].eq('Johnson').cumsum().astype(bool)]
```

I think the winner could be another person so also you can check 0:

```
df.loc[:df['Winner'].eq(0).idxmin() - 1]
```

---

**Output**

```
  Position Winner
0        1      0
1        2      0
2        3      0
3        4      0
4        5      0
```